# General Relativity manipulating tensors, tensor indices meaning

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I have a couple of questions regarding manipulating tensors.

Firstly, what is the difference between the Tensor $T^{a}\ _{b}$ and $T_a\ ^b$. I understand that the upper indices refers to dual basis and lower indices refer to basis. In my textbook it says the tensor works like $t_{ab} = t(e_a,e_b)$ and $t^{ab} = t(e^a,e^b)$. I also understand that the left or right indices refers to the column or row of the tensor in matrix form respectively. So would that mean for $T^{a}\ _{b}$, its rows are in basis vectors and its columns are in dual basis vectors? vice versa for $T_a\ ^b$.

My other questions is how you derive the transformation of the basis vectors. From my textbook I found $ds^2 = dx^b e_b = dx'^{a}e'_a$. Since $dx'^a = \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^b}dx^b$, you get $e'_a = \frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x'^a}e_b$. I am struggling to get the similar result for the dual basis vectors, $e'^a = \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^b}e^b$. For this I have tried using the metric to raise the indices from the first result:

$e'^a = g^{ad}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x'^d}e_b$,

but I am unsure how to resolve this or if this is even the correct method. Unfortunately the textbook doesn't show how it does it for the dual basis.

Comment: Which textbook are you using?

Comment: Tip: Only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: I am using the textbook, General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists Book by Anthony N. Lasenby, George Efstathiou, and Michael Paul Hobson

Answer (score 1):

About the first part, you nearly answered your own question: it is indeed exactly because the definition of tensors arises naturally out of multilinear maps such as $t(e^a,e^b)$ that the order of arguments is also reflected in the index notation, e.g. $t^{ab} \equiv t(e^a,e^b)$ , $M_b{} ^a{} _c \equiv M(e_b,e^a, e_c)$, etc.

Importantly, note that in your example $t(e^a,e^b)$ and $t(e_a,e_b)$ *cannot* be the same object. In this representation, a tensor has a unique order for its argument types, for example: if the first $2$ arguments are vectors and the last $3$ are co-vectors, you can't mix them around, and indeed the index notation will also reflect that.

There's no special advantage in thinking about it in terms of columns and rows, such analogies become irrelevant in any case when the tensor has more than $2$ indices. It's also not very important when actually working with the index notation, because once you evaluate a tensor in a specific basis it acts more like a number, and keeping track of the relative order between upper & lower indices, is quite often just a useful reminder for the source of the object you're working with, though I'll provide a slight reservation about that in a second.
In contrast, the  order of indices at each level separately ("upstairs" & "downstairs") is *always* crucially important for calculational purposes. You'll get your calculation messed up quickly if you mistake $T^{ab}_{cd}$ for $T^{ba}_{dc}$! :)

There is a scenario where keeping track of the entire relative position of indices is important, and that is when "raising and lowering" indices. Suppose we have a tensor that looks like $T_{abcd}$ and we raise the $b$ index (via the metric tensor, say) so it becomes: $T_a{} ^b{} _{cd}$, now, if we just wrote $T^b_{acd}$, "forgetting" about the original placement of $b$ we may run into a problem: suppose somewhere further in our calculation, we have to lower $b$ again, where does it descend into? :) So you see that this bookkeeping can in some cases be important, which is why it is indeed a very good practice to follow.

Regarding the second issue, you got the right idea by multiplying the equation by the metric tensor to raise the indices, you're just missing a few observaions. I prefer to put the primes on the indices to distinguish between bases, we have:

$$e_{d'} = \frac{\partial{x^b}}{\partial{x^{d'}}}e_b$$

Multiplying both sides by $g^{a'd'}$ gives us:

$$
e^{a'} = \frac{\partial{x^b}}{\partial{x^{d'}}}g^{a'd'}e_b\tag{1}
$$

The trick is to notice that what we have on the right hand side is nearly a transformation of the metric tensor $g^{a'd'}$ to the unprimed basis, we are just lacking a factor of $\frac{\partial{x^a}}{\partial{x^{a'}}}$ and we can obtain $g^{ab}$. To be explicit we're gonna use the fact that:

$$\frac{\partial{x^a}}{\partial{x^{a{'}}}}\frac{\partial{x^b}}{\partial{x^{d'}}}g^{a'd'}=g^{ab}$$

But of course to do that, we have to multiply the RHS of $(1)$ by $\frac{\partial{x^a}}{\partial{x^{a'}}}\frac{\partial{x^{a'}}}{\partial{x^{a}}}$ so that nothing is changed (this can also be shown to be the identity transformation):

\begin{aligned}
e^{a'} &= \frac{\partial{x^{a'}}}{\partial{x^{a}}}\frac{\partial{x^a}}{\partial{x^{a{'}}}}\frac{\partial{x^b}}{\partial{x^{d'}}}g^{a'd'}e_b \\ &= \frac{\partial{x^{a'}}}{\partial{x^{a}}}g^{ab}e_b \\ &=  \frac{\partial{x^{a'}}}{\partial{x^{a}}}e^a
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you, this answer was amazing!

Comment: You're welcome 